# retrieving specific columns from a dictionary of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary with a string for keys and pandas dataframes as items/values. Each dataframe has identical column names, length, etc.  What i'd like to know is if i could work from this structure alone and pass, say, all data from column 5 of each dataframe as an argument into a function such as PCA?

Currently i am looping through each key, grabbing the desired column and merging it into a new dataframe but that seems incredibly ugly...

Answer (score 2):

You could be using panels. There's a good example of what you want to do in the pandas documentation:

```
In [109]: df = DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
   .....:                 'b': np.random.randn(3)})
   .....: 

In [110]: df
Out[110]: 
     a         b
0  foo -2.006481
1  bar  0.301016
2  baz  0.059117

In [111]: data = {'item1': df, 'item2': df}

In [112]: panel = Panel.from_dict(data, orient='minor')

In [113]: panel['a']
Out[113]: 
  item1 item2
0   foo   foo
1   bar   bar
2   baz   baz

In [114]: panel['b']
Out[114]: 
      item1     item2
0 -2.006481 -2.006481
1  0.301016  0.301016
2  0.059117  0.059117
```